# FontAwesome icons doesnt show up after being downloaded?(works with URL, doesnt with SRC)

Tags: css, font-awesome

I've been using fontawesome for one of my web projects and it works fine when I use the CDN link as its stylesheet but when I want to have everything locally and download FontAwesome(zip file) from the website, it becomes messy and shows multiple icons as some kind of bad zoom problem over its png file of icons.

the only change is

this

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

into this

```
  <link src="assets/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Again, the problem isnt that its not working, its how it shows multiple icons.

Comment: `link` tag doesn't have `src` attribute, use `href` no matter it is CDN or local link

Comment: Use href attribute in both instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assure you have downloaded the full package with correct version from the FontAwesome website and use a correct link, such as:

```
<link href="assets/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" >
```

Reset your browsers cache.

Assure that the  or  element you use, uses the FontAwesome font family. For example:

```
<i class="fa-pencil" title="Edit"></i>
```

but

```
<i class="fa fa-pencil" title="Edit"></i>
It won't work if you have something as the following in your CSS:

* {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif !important;   
}
```

If you are using IE, just dont...

If this doesn't work, just give it one hour or two(trust me sometimes browser plays jokes on itself), if problem was persistant, check https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Troubleshooting